# brand new battery brand new alternator car will not start even with a jump

Tags: electrical

2001 Toyota Sienna. Had a blowout on the driver side which messed up the wires. Tape them up and lost hazards. Recently car died while driving took it to the mechanic and got a brand new alternator and a brand new battery was told I have an electrical problem and to untape my wires and re-tape them. After I'm taping them the car will not start. The starter clicks so I tried tapping it with a hammer. Now the car will not start and no lights will appear on the dashboard

Comment: Perhaps one or some of the wires shorted and knocked out a fuse? Want to solder heat shrink then tape if you can. Tape will just dry out and let water in

Comment: Well, if you're just blundering around doing random wire repairs without any real skill, then that'll be a real impediment to the car working again.  It's not enough to tape wires, they must also be spliced.    A starter clicking is a discharged battery.  Discharged is not the same as dead, discharged is like getting a new phone whose battery is at 3%.  Start by charging up the battery.

Comment: I would check those wires - did you just wrap tape around the outside or did you repair each wire individually?

Comment: I'm not versed in wiring what so ever but I do have a good understanding of how it's done. I was told by my mechanic to go through each wire individually and replace the ones that need to be replaced by slicing and heat shrinking